# How to create a new model entity, set its values, and save it?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I do it like this. It works but looks so ugly. And I don't have any clue to make it more meaningful.
I'm using .NET Framework 3.5 and MVC2

*TRY TO Explain a little more...*
With the following code, I set value to 'temp' again and again. if table 'temp' have 100 fields, then I have to set value 100 times. That's what I mean ugly.

```
//
    // POST: /TableA/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(TableA formdata)
    {
        TableA temp = new TableA();

        //A foreign key model in another TableB
        var tbb = myDB.TableB.First(a => a.Id == formdata.TableB.Id);
        temp.TableB = tbb;

        //fields in this table
        temp.field1= formdata.field1;
        temp.field2= formdata.field2;
        temp.field3= formdata.field3;

        myDB.AddToTableA(temp);
        myDB.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Separating code in layers** usually helps, because you don't mix UI with business layer or data access layer... if that's what you asked, because it's rather hard to know what you's like to change in your code.

Otherwise your code looks as a mix of everything, becomes hard to maintain and understand what it does.

### Edit

Instead of setting every property manually, you can do either:

1. Use object initializers (C# 3.0 feature)

   ```
   TableA record = new TableA {
       TableB = myDB.TableB.First(a => a.Id == formdata.TableB.Id),
       Field1 = ... ,
       ...
   };
   ```
2. Use static factory methods provided by entity classes:

   ```
   TableA record = TableA.CreateTableA(/* provide all values as method parameters */);
   ```

Comment: Maybe I did not ask my question clearly because I don't know what is the solution I want. I explained it a little more in the original post.

Comment: @hbrlovehaku: Does my edited answer provide the help you seek?

Comment: Use object initializers (C# 3.0 feature) is what I'm looking for. Thanks very much. And another problem is what is the corresponding way of updating a model?

Comment: @hbrlovehaku: Either (1) load your entity from DB context, update its values and `SaveChanges` or (2) attach an entity to DB context, update its values and `SaveChanges`. **BTW**: don't forget to accept my answer as the correct one, thus rewarding me any yourself with some reputation points.

Comment: @hbrlovehaku: that would have to be a different question because it's out of scope of your current question. Just ask a question how to do updates in EF and community will help.